# Why does error is not specific to resolve when running in aosp 9

Tags: java, android, linux, android-source

I am using aosp 9 by customizing Launcher. Launcher works in Tablet but when I select as " Default as Home" It displays a black screen.

Instead of using logcat, I used

```
# logcat -b system | grep "launcher"
```

Because Logcat displaying many logs. Inorder to filter only launcher, I used this.

I can trace log error as,

```
 12-02 12:11:02.938   397   711 W ActivityManager:   Force finishing activity com.android.launcher/com.android.launcher2.Launcher
12-02 12:11:03.056   397   711 I ActivityManager: Process com.android.launcher (pid 1654) has died: fore TOP 
12-02 12:12:16.708   397   616 I PackageManager: Setting last chosen activity com.android.launcher3/.Launcher for user 0:
12-02 12:12:16.711   397   616 I ActivityManager: START u0 {act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.HOME] flg=0x13000100 cmp=com.android.launcher3/.Launcher} from uid 0
12-02 12:12:29.674   397  1649 I PackageManager: Setting last chosen activity com.android.launcher/com.android.launcher2.Launcher for user 0:
12-02 12:12:29.677   397  1649 I ActivityManager: START u0 {act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.HOME] flg=0x13200000 cmp=com.android.launcher/com.android.launcher2.Launcher (has extras)} from uid 1000
12-02 12:12:29.812   397   414 I ActivityManager: Start proc 1730:com.android.launcher/u0a10 for activity com.android.launcher/com.android.launcher2.Launcher
12-02 12:12:30.151   397  1649 W ActivityManager:   Force finishing activity com.android.launcher/com.android.launcher2.Launcher
12-02 12:12:30.158   397  1649 W ActivityManager:   Force finishing activity com.android.launcher3/.Launcher
12-02 12:12:30.276   397   446 I ActivityManager: Process com.android.launcher (pid 1730) has died: fore TOP 
12-02 12:12:32.706   397  1590 I PackageManager: Setting last chosen activity com.android.launcher/com.android.launcher2.Launcher for user 0:
12-02 12:12:32.709   397  1590 I ActivityManager: START u0 {act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.HOME] flg=0x13000100 cmp=com.android.launcher/com.android.launcher2.Launcher} from uid 0
12-02 12:12:32.862   397   414 I ActivityManager: Start proc 1783:com.android.launcher/u0a10 for activity com.android.launcher/com.android.launcher2.Launcher
12-02 12:12:33.298   397  1590 W ActivityManager:   Force finishing activity com.android.launcher/com.android.launcher2.Launcher
12-02 12:12:33.405   397   711 I ActivityManager: Process com.android.launcher (pid 1783) has died: fore TOP 
12-02 12:12:43.301   397  1649 I PackageManager: Setting last chosen activity com.android.launcher3/.Launcher for user 0:
12-02 12:12:43.305   397  1809 I ActivityManager: START u0 {act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.HOME] flg=0x13200000 cmp=com.android.launcher3/.Launcher (has extras)} from uid 1000
12-02 12:12:43.758   808   808 I chatty  : uid=10026(com.android.launcher3) identical 1 line
12-02 12:21:08.761   397  1649 I PackageManager: Setting last chosen activity com.android.launcher/com.android.launcher2.Launcher for user 0:
12-02 12:21:08.764   397  1649 I ActivityManager: START u0 {act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.HOME] flg=0x13200000 cmp=com.android.launcher/com.android.launcher2.Launcher (has extras)} from uid 1000
12-02 12:21:08.908   397   414 I ActivityManager: Start proc 2045:com.android.launcher/u0a10 for activity com.android.launcher/com.android.launcher2.Launcher
12-02 12:21:09.331   397   408 W ActivityManager:   Force finishing activity com.android.launcher/com.android.launcher2.Launcher
12-02 12:21:09.341   397   408 W ActivityManager:   Force finishing activity com.android.launcher3/.Launcher
12-02 12:21:09.495   397   447 I ActivityManager: Process com.android.launcher (pid 2045) has died: fore TOP 
12-02 12:21:10.689   397   447 I PackageManager: Setting last chosen activity com.android.launcher/com.android.launcher2.Launcher for user 0:
12-02 12:21:10.694   397   408 I ActivityManager: START u0 {act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.HOME] flg=0x13000100 cmp=com.android.launcher/com.android.launcher2.Launcher} from uid 0
12-02 12:21:10.844   397   414 I ActivityManager: Start proc 2074:com.android.launcher/u0a10 for activity com.android.launcher/com.android.launcher2.Launcher
12-02 12:21:11.290   397   408 W ActivityManager:   Force finishing activity com.android.launcher/com.android.launcher2.Launcher
12-02 12:21:11.428   397  1756 I ActivityManager: Process com.android.launcher (pid 2074) has died: fore TOP
```

There is no such specific error to display like NullPointerException or ClassNotFoundException. It simply displays as force finishing activity without displaying in which activity. So in this case, how to rectify this error?

Kindly provide solution please.

Comment: Post a logcat without filter (or adb logcat *:E, there is no info on the one you posted.). Also if it's crashing all the time, chatty may be hiding it, take logcat after first crash.